# Having hard time binding array of object from web service call to wpf listbox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, binding

i started a WPF application (with vs 2008 sp1) which connects to a web service to get Collection of objects.
I can be `contactInfo[]` or `groupInfo[]`.
 here is my `main.xaml.cs`

```
 public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //service.addContactCompleted +=new addContactCompletedEventHandler(addContactCompleted);
        service.getContactsCompleted += new getContactsCompletedEventHandler(getContactsCompleted);
        fillContents();
    }

private void getContactsCompleted(object sender, getContactsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //e.Result return contactInfo[]
            contactListBox.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    public void fillContents()
    {
        service.getContactsAsync(session.key, null);


    }
```

and this is my `main.xaml`

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="contactInfo" ObjectType="{x:Type serviceAdmin:contactInfo}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
                <ListBox Margin="-146,-124,-143,-118.808" Name="contactListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource contactInfo}}" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding fullName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <!--<toolkit:DataGrid Margin="-146,-124,-150,-118.808" Name="contactGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>-->
</Grid>
```

this partially works but just that it returns repeated values. it just repeats which ever comes first.I'll like to know what i'm doing wrong here.Can anyone shed some light?? thanks for reading this!!

Comment: This is just a guess, but you are accessing a UI object from another thread (the thread on which the event is raised)... Try wrapping the line where you set the ItemsSource with an appropriate Invoke (or BeginInvoke)...

Comment: Why are you setting the ItemsSource both in XAML and in code? In addition, if you set a breakpoint when it's assigned in code, are the values in e.Result what you'd expect?

Comment: thanks for you guys trying to help me,. i really appreciate it.Now the repetition fault was from what the ws was returning, i checked from debugging.  
@Aviad thanks my way of doing async works but i have one question i'm trying to do the same thing for group as in calling async but its seems not working for both
@justABill thanks for the tip, you know i have read things from google and i guess i overdid, so i removed the itemsource from xaml, you can try help me with the question i ask Aviad P i you can thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are binding your ListBox to the wrong source. First of all, I don't really see why you need to have to ObjectDataSource at all. You can just bind the ItemsSource of the ListBox to your collection, like you did. But also (as a commenter pointed out), keep in mind that you are accessing the UI on a different thread, so you should use calls to Dispatcher to fill up your listbox.
Maybe something like this:

```
 public main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    service.getContactsCompleted += new getContactsCompletedEventHandler(getContactsCompleted);
    fillContents();
}

private void getContactsCompleted(object sender, getContactsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //e.Result return contactInfo[]
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<List<contactInfo>>(list => contactListBox.ItemsSource = list), e.Result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public void fillContents()
{
    service.getContactsAsync(session.key, null);
}
```

your xaml can be greatly simplified to this:

```
<Grid>
   <ListBox Margin="-146,-124,-143,-118.808" Name="contactListBox" DisplayMember="fullName" />
</Grid>
```

HTH,
Roel

Comment: wow! awesome,you are right about the ObjectDatasource, and i removed it. now i want to present the data so 
    ` <!- .....-->
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock>
<Label Content="{Binding fullName}" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"/> <LineBreak/>
<Label Content="{Binding mobile}" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="DimGray" />  <Label Content="{Binding email}" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="10" Foreground="DimGray"/></TextBlock> </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate><!- ... -->`
will what you are suggesting still work? thanks bruv

Comment: By the way will the Dispatcher help me calling another web service method asynchronously , it seems that second one is not working property, maybe due to the fact the share the single asmx connection, is there a way around it? thanks for helping!

Comment: Glad to help. The `DisplayMember` will only work if you want to display just one property. Indeed, you'll have to use an `ItemTemplate` to display different properties.

Comment: No, the Dispatcher is just there to execute calls on your UI thread.